# How to force user to type more than any number of characters in password field

Tags: asp.net

I want to force user to type more than 6 characters in password field.we cannot usee range validator because password characters can be mix(i.e.Numeric or alphabates or special characters)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `RegularExpressionValidator` if you're using validators for other things, might as well stay with that:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valMinLength" runat="server"
 ControlToValidate="myPasswordBox"
 ErrorMessage="Password should have at least 6 characters"
 ValidationExpression="/{6,}/" />
```

Comment: Presumably you would want to not count trailing or leading spaces though.

Comment: @Martin - I agree for almost all password cases, in that case just update the regex, but whatever check you want will work.  I wasn't sure based on the question since the restriction was noted as an example, so left it wide open.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RegEx validator that it must match the pattern

```
[^\s]{6,}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**CustomValidator**](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_customvalidator)

```
<script  runat="server">
bool CheckPasswordLen()
{
   if (textbox1.Text.Length < 6)
    return false;
   else
    return true;
}     

</script>     



<asp:textbox id="textbox1" runat="server">
<asp:CustomValidator id="valCustom" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="textbox1"    
    OnServerValidate="CheckPasswordLen"
    ErrorMessage="*Password must be greater than 6 characters"*
</asp:CustomValidator>
```